# Android Wear Install watch face automatically from wear app

Tags: android

I have an Android Wear App and I have Android Wear Watch Face. They are withing the same project and different package ("app" and "watch") however I need to install them separately. How can I pack my watch face with the wear app so when I install the app, the watch face is installed automatically?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can not do this. Watch face app also is a wear app. Two wear app can not have same package name. But you can put the watch face code to wear app .

Comment: I've edited my question - they are withing the same project, but are different packages - "app" and "watch"

Comment: Also you can not do this. You can not install one app and automatically install other app.

Comment: But when I install Google Fit I also get two watch faces - so it should be possible design-wise?

Comment: The Google Fit watch faces code is in the Google Fit app. The watch faces are not standalone apk.